# Simple Pairwise Difference of vector

Tags: r, difference

I want to take the pairwise differences of a vector using which I have seen people use dist here is an example of the type of data I am working with:

```
v <- c(1:4)
names(v) <- c('a','b','c','d')
v <- data.frame(t(v))
dist(v)
```

Currently dist(v) produces dist(0), when I would expect:

```
 a b c
 b 1    
 c 2 1  
 d 3 2 1
```

I simply want the diagonal of dist(v) which I know I can extract using the diag() function. If there is a way to not have to use the diag() function that would be nice as well.

Comment: `dist` computes the `dist`ance between _rows_ whereas `v` is a 1 row "data.frame"; you could use `dist(t(v))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method using `combn`

```
# convert to a vector
vNew <- as.numeric(v[1,])
# calculate pair-wise differences
t(rbind(combn(vNew,2), combn(vNew, 2, FUN=dist)))

    [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    1
[2,]    1    3    2
[3,]    1    4    3
[4,]    2    3    1
[5,]    2    4    2
[6,]    3    4    1
```

Here, the first two columns are the elements of the vector and the third column is the distance.

Answer (score 2):

There is one step too many in your code, use this and you get your desired result:

```
v <- c(1:4)
names(v) <- c('a','b','c','d')
dist(v)
  a b c
  b 1    
  c 2 1  
  d 3 2 1
```

Comment: I am trying to reproduce my issues, by creating a data frame with the same ugly format that I currently put up in the example. So I do not have one step too many, that is the error I am getting and the example code is how I am giving a reproducible result.